# how to prevent shutdown signal from android device when the apps is running?

Tags: android

The apps has some important data transfer during some process. I wanna know how to disable the shutdown signal of device unless the device is out of the electricity.

Comment: What does it mean by shutdown signal

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do some things in background, you can use a service, i think is better

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you should be able to avoid the user to turn off their phones, and I don't think you actually can.

What you should do is somehow save the state of the data transfer before the shutdown, and after it's on again, resume that transfer. And maybe tell the user to wait until the transfer is done before shutting the phone down and place a notification telling the user how much is left to finish the transfer.

Also, as Saulo Aires says, if you want to do things in background, use a service.

You may want to check the Activities lifecycle: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html#Lifecycle

And the Services lifecycle: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#Lifecycle

Also, read the differences between those two (if you don't know it already) and pick the one that best fits your needs.